# UDP Hole Punching: Unable to send data from server to client (client to server OK)

Tags: firewall, nat

Starting with server-A (globally reachable via static IP), I bind a UDP socket to 0.0.0.0:25000.

Then with client-A behind a (residential) NAT, I bind a UDP socket to 0.0.0.0:25000. Client-A then sends a packet to server-A.

Server-A receives the packet. Server-A records the remote socket, K, from where the packet was NAT'ed. Server-A sends a packet to K with the intention that the NAT forward the packet to client-A.

However, client-A does not receive the packet. On the NAT, when I enable port triggering on port 25000 for UDP, then it works. However, in the making of a p2p app, I'd prefer to stay away from requiring clients to go into the router settings to make the program work. How can I punch a hole through the firewall such that the communication is bidirectional?

Comment: I think you need to use UPnP from the client side, like torrent clients do.

Comment: It works using UPnP. However, this is only if the client if behind a residential NAT. When the client switches to using cellular tethering (implied symmetrical NAT), UDP datagrams sent from the server do not reach the client. UPnP, of course, does not do anything in such cases. Since the server is on a well-reachable static IP, how can I get UDP to send to the client?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the source of libs that implement UPnP?
https://github.com/picotorrent/libtorrent/blob/RC_1_2/src/upnp.cpp
https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/master/libtransmission/upnp.c

Comment: And, I don't know what is your mobile, but if it is an iPhone Apple ecosystem tends to prefer NAT-PMP over UPnP. I'm not aware of the actual differences when configuring the network. Those same libs have code for NAT-PMP too.